# Change default product tab

Tags: tags

I want to be able to change the 'TV Stands' tag on the site back to Products (See Below) due to the additions of other products. I have search high and low and can not see where to change this! 
[image]

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: is TV Stands category?

Comment: TV Stands is a category in its own right, however this tag is appearing under every category. Having searched the net, it looks like the default is 'products' and its been changed, I now want to change it back

Answer (score 2):

To turn on template path hints in Magento:

1.log into the magento back-end admin
2.Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
3.Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
4.Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
5.Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.
Remember to clear your cache.

[image: Here You can find which file to edit to change the discriptin]

Or Check For Translations in Locale Folder of your theme

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check first:

1. Translations: Maybe `Recently Viewed Products` has been translated
   to `Recently Viewed Tv Stands` In
   System/Configuration/Advanced/Developer you can turn on inline
   translations for the front end, this will show you if it's
   translated, and where the translation occurs.
2. Templates" Maybe your template was edited, in System/Configuration/Advanced/Developer/Debug you can also turn on Template Path Hints. You'll need to change your configuration scope to the website first, and then you'll know what template is being used to display the block.